# Custom font color for Powershell output

Tags: powershell, colors, output

Let's take the powershell command `Write-Host "red text" -Fore red`
this displays "red text" in a foreground of red. 
But, you want the text to be displayed in a slightly lighter
font color, light red.

Is there a way to do this and get any foreground color (and background) in the RGB spectrum using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      1      0

(0..256).ForEach{write-host "`e[38;5;$($_)m[$_]"} # background color
(0..256).ForEach{write-host "`e[48;5;$($_)m[$_]"} # Foreground color
```

Comment: you may want to add a note that this requires a console that can use ANSI escape sequences. as an example, the default windows 7 console does not support such. [*grin*]

Comment: I don't even know if I want it

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there a way to do this for background too? I tried to do something like ```write-host "`e[7;6;$(60)m[60]"``` but that resulted in a really weird alternating background.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? In particular the code in the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

See this: https://github.com/PoshCode/Pansies
It is a PowerShell module that does this.
There is an issue here related to your question:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14588

Please click the above link for more information.